# OpenLayers to display google maps

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to display google maps in my web application but it displays blank. My map.js is as follows

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false';
head.appendChild(script);

map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    allOverlays: true
});

var google_map_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google Map Layer', {});

map.addLayer(google_map_layer);
```

I am using openlayers version 2.10. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console for JavaScript errors also have a look at the tutorials:

- http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/BaseLayersAndOverlays
- http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Layer/Google
- http://openlayers.org/blog/2010/07/10/google-maps-v3-for-openlayers/